# Dockerized app throws read operation timed out error and exits

Tags: node.js, express, docker, ironmq

I've an **express** application that takes data from an **IronMQ push queue.** I've **Dockerized** this app and on running the application in a Docker Container, after some idle time say 20-30 mins, the App throws an error and exits out:

```
Error: read tcp 192.168.59.3:50346->192.168.59.103:2376: read: operation timed out
```

**My boot2docker ip --> 192.168.59.103**

I've forwarded the port at 3000.

I've tried using process object to catch uncaught exception but to no help.

**Note:** I've ran the app outside of docker on my local, and the app runs fine without throwing an error and logging out. So the problem seems to with docker.

Comment: what do the logs of IronMQ say? Can you `nc` 192.168.59.103:2376 from the outside? Can you `docker exec` into both containers and check if the connection is still open.

Comment: @CFrei: I logged inside the conatiner, the connection in fine. I've checked the app is running in the background and running exactly as it is supposed to

Comment: I'm wondering why is it throwing that err msg and exiting out of the console while still running in the background.

Comment: What version of Docker are you running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it turns out, when you execute the docker run command in the attached mode i.e with the -a parameter or wiihout the -d parameter, something like:

`docker run -a <imageID>` **or** `docker run <imageID>`

Docker detaches from the container by default after sometime and runs the container in detached mode. Meaning your application runs fine in the background.

Hence the error: timed out

**Note:** This is not explicitly mentioned in the docker docs, so thought this could be documented here for future reference.